# Flutter Navigator 2.0 - Router does not receive deep link when app is launched from URL?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, deep-linking, flutter-navigation

I'm using Flutter Navigator 2.0 with Nested Routers - there's a main router created by calling `MaterialApp.router()` and child routers created as `Router()` widgets with proper RouterDelegates (child routers are used as pages for bottom navigation).

In current use case, I want to use a deep link to open one of the pages inside a nested router, so I followed the instructions and configured:

1. Android Manifest to receive custom schema and host URL's
2. `RouteInformationParser` to parse it into my own model
3. `PlatformRouteInformationProvider` to notify all nested routers about route change

Everything works fine when application is in foreground (f.e. on splash screen) - I receive a pushRoute event and deep link is handled correctly by the root and nested `Router` widgets. However, when the application is not launched, I do not receive an initialRoute set to my deep link, and I get the default, empty `RouteInformation` instead. Why does that happen?  Here are my code samples:

Flutter `MainActivity` configuration in Android Manifest:

```xml
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- For deeplinking -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled"
                android:value="true" />

            <!-- Accepts links in format myapp://*.myapp.com/ -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="*.myapp.com"
                    android:scheme="myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Main Application class (used in RunApp):

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static PlatformRouteInformationProvider routeInformationProvider =
      PlatformRouteInformationProvider(
    initialRouteInformation: const RouteInformation(),
  );

  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => FutureBuilder(
        future: AppInit.initApp(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return _app();
        },
      );

  Widget _app() => MultiRepositoryProvider(
        providers: AppRepositoryProviders().list,
        child: MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: AppBlocProviders().list,
          child: MaterialApp.router(
            supportedLocales: LocalizationConfig.supportedLocales,
            localizationsDelegates: LocalizationConfig.localizationDelegates,
            theme: LightTheme().themeData,
            routerDelegate: UserSessionRouter(),
            routeInformationParser: AppRouteInformationParser(),
            routeInformationProvider: routeInformationProvider,
            backButtonDispatcher: RootBackButtonDispatcher(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    ...
}
```

RouteInformationParser implementation:

```dart
class AppRouteInformationParser extends RouteInformationParser<DeepLinkRoute> {
  @override
  Future<DeepLinkRoute> parseRouteInformation(
      RouteInformation routeInformation) async {
    if (routeInformation.location.isNullOrEmpty) {
      return DeepLinkRoute.none();
    } else {
      return DeepLinkParser.parse(routeInformation.location!).fold(
        (data) => DeepLinkRoute(
          link: data,
          route: _getRouteFromDeeplink(data),
        ),
        (error) => DeepLinkRoute.none(),
      );
    }
  }

  RouteDefinition _getRouteFromDeeplink(DeepLink deepLink) {
    switch (deepLink.path) {
      case '/auth/signup':
        return AppRoutes.authSignup;
      default:
        return AppRoutes.none;
    }
  }

  @override
  RouteInformation restoreRouteInformation(DeepLinkRoute configuration) =>
      RouteInformation(
        location: configuration.link.path,
        state: configuration.link.queryParams,
      );
}
```

The screen with nested (child) router:

```dart
class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthScreenState createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  final AuthRouter _routerDelegate = AuthRouter();
  ChildBackButtonDispatcher? _backButtonDispatcher;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _initBackButtonDispatcher();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  void _initBackButtonDispatcher() {
    _backButtonDispatcher ??=
        ChildBackButtonDispatcher(context.router.backButtonDispatcher!);
    _backButtonDispatcher?.takePriority();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => SigninScreenCubit(
                    usersRepository: context.read<UsersRepository>(),
                  ))
        ],
        child: Router(
          routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
          backButtonDispatcher: _backButtonDispatcher,
          routeInformationParser: AppRouteInformationParser(),
          routeInformationProvider:
              MyApp.routeInformationProvider,
        ),
      );
}
```

And I test the deep linking with this command:

```sh
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "$1"
```

With given classes, the deep link when launching the app is always empty. My best guess is the instance of `RouteInformationProvider`:

```dart
  static PlatformRouteInformationProvider routeInformationProvider =
      PlatformRouteInformationProvider(initialRouteInformation: const RouteInformation());
```

Or some kind of configuration error, but I'm not able to identify it myself.

UPDATE:

I've tested this on iOS, and surprisingly, it works completely reverse than Android - when app is killed, it opens fine with a deep link, but when it's in foreground `Router` never gets update and `RouteInformationProvider` and `RouteInformationParser` are both never called. I've found some related issues on Flutter GitHub repository, and although they are closed, I don't think they solve my issue. [This issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82550) seems to be the almost same as my problem, but I've taken a look at [the PR that's supposed to solve it](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/27874) and I can see other users also reporting problems with deep links on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because your `routeInformationProvider` is overriding that value with an empty route when the app has just been opened instead of receiving the proper route from the operating system.

Changing the empty`routeInformationProvider` to the one actually used by the Navigator by default.

```dart
  static PlatformRouteInformationProvider routeInformationProvider =
      PlatformRouteInformationProvider(
    initialRouteInformation: RouteInformation(
        location: PlatformDispatcher.instance.defaultRouteName),
  );
```

Keep in mind that you need to import `dart:ui`.

This will use the specific behavior for android and iOS for reading the deep link route when launching the application as it receives the route from the operating system.

This does not fix the iOS problem of the question though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've tried setting the value of initial route to different things, but I didn't know that Platform can be used to retrieve initial route that way. I've noticed that using your solution with development channel of Flutter seems to fix the deep link handling when the application is in background. It doesn't however solve the iOS issue when the app is in foreground.

Comment: I see. I have no hardware to test iOS devices. So I cannot help you there. I am glad this fixed the Android problem though.

Comment: @Cavitedev -- I was able to get my listeners to recognize the parameters being passed through a deep link.  However, that listener is in main(), and I am not able to use Navigator 2.0 API to route to the page which is determined by the values captured from the [deep link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72926880/how-do-i-automatically-route-when-in-flutter-from-within-main)

Comment: I've never tried doing it on the main method, but I recommend you to debug the parser method when you open through command the deep link. There are usually problems with blems with the manifest or with the received input

Comment: @Cavitedev thanks for getting back. I am not quite sure what you mean. I current can pass values from my listener in main(). But I need a way to go to a specific route once those parameters are available. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73059450/how-can-i-route-using-gorouter-in-flutter-without-context